# HTML/Javascript Input type="text" - How to shows text different from value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, text, input

Actually i have a datalist:

```
<datalist id='modelsList'>
   <option value='1'>Dummy1</option>
   <option value='2'>Dummy2</option>
</datalist>
```

This is used in an input:

```
<input type='text' name='dummy' autocomplete='off' list='modelsList' value=''/>
```

If i start typing Dummy2 and then i click on the dropdown list result the textbox shows 2. I need to find a way to have 2 as value but Dummy2 as text.

I cannot use a drop-down list (select tag)

Comment: what exactly you want??

Comment: Please provide some test input and output.

Comment: HTML `input` doesn't work that way. HTML `textarea` does work that way, only without the `value` and `type` attributes.

Comment: that's illegal html. inputs are singleton tags. they do not have content, and there has NEVER been a `</input>` closing tag.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to describe a [placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)?

Comment: `"Is there a way to make something similar?"` - That depends on what you're actually trying to do, which you haven't really explained.

Comment: It will be good if you first donate some time to reading because these are basic. you can get some good  tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: *no lo so, mi amico* - you tagged this as javascript, *why?* your question is unclear for quite a few reasons. *no capito la tua questione*.

Comment: la vostra questione non e chiara - Not my downvote btw ;-)

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited my question, is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, my solution as per you want check it out...
You can use input event for achieving such functionality,

> HTML

```
<input type='text' id='dummy' list='modelsList'/>
<datalist id='modelsList'>
     <option value='1'>Dummy1</option>
     <option value='2'>Dummy2</option>
</datalist>
```

> Jquery

```
$("#dummy").on('input', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if($('#modelsList option').filter(function(){
        return this.value === val; 
    }).length) {
       var option = $('#modelsList').find('option[value="' + val + '"]');
       $(this).val(option.text());
    }
});
```

also check [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/d5bobz5k/10/) of the above code.

Answer (score 1):

The format for a text `input` in HTML5 is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="Value" placeholder="Placeholder Text">
```

As a user types in their content, the `value` changes.

---

You may be getting confused with `textarea`:

```
<textarea name="name">Value</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to put a `textarea` tag, you have to know that the `value` attribute is invalid, but perhaps if you want to use it instead of `input`, and the format is similar as you put:

```
<textarea name="name">contentHere</textarea>
```